# Login to Windows account simultaneously? (RDP)

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, remote-desktop, remote-access

I'm trying to enable an RDP session in Windows 10 *while* my parents are logged into the same account. Is this possible? I know there are third-party solutions (vnc, teamviewer, etc) but it would be nice to achieve this without installing more software.

Answer (score 4):

Impossible.

If you don’t want to use third-party software or tools, you cannot Login Windows client system(Windows 10) when another user has logged on. Your parents will be logged off when you remote to the PC.

Only server version systems(Windows Server 2012, 2012R2, 2016) support Multiple RDP Sessions.

If you prefer to using Microsoft product, maybe Skype share desktop can meet your demand. Another choice: Windows Remote Assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Currently this is impossible without [using tools](https://github.com/stascorp/rdpwrap) that hack Licensing system of Windows.

In newer [Windows 10 version (1809 or 1903) Microsoft could support this](https://windowsreport.com/remote-desktop-multiple-users-windows-10/):

> The companion rumor to Microsoft removing RDSH from Server is that
>   they will be *adding* a multi-user, multiwin-based option to Windows
>   10. In other words, Microsoft is taking Terminal Server out of Windows Server and moving into Windows 10. If true, this is fantastic.